# Ubuntu Bash Script executing a command with spaces

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bit of an issue and i've tried several ways to fix this but i can't seem to.

So i have two shell scripts.

**background.sh**: This runs a given command in the background and redirect's output.

```
#!/bin/bash

if test -t 1; then
  exec 1>/dev/null
fi

if test -t 2; then
  exec 2>/dev/null
fi

"$@" &
```

**main.sh**: This file simply starts the emulator (genymotion) as a background process.

```
#!/bin/bash
GENY_DIR="/home/user/Documents/MyScript/watchdog/genymotion"
BK="$GENY_DIR/background.sh"
DEVICE="164e959b-0e15-443f-b1fd-26d101edb4a5"
CMD="$BK player --vm-name $DEVICE"
$CMD
```

This works fine when i have NO spaces in my directory. However, when i try to do: `GENY_DIR="home/user/Documents/My Script/watchdog/genymotion"`

which i have no choice at the moment. I get an error saying that the file or directory cannot be found. I tried to put `"$CMD"` in quote but it didn't work.

You can test this by trying to run anything as a background process, doesn't have to be an emulator.

Any advice or feedback would be appreciated. I also tried to do.

`BK="'$BK'"`

or

`BK="\"$BK\""`

or

`BK=$( echo "$BK" | sed 's/ /\\ /g' )`

Comment: Your directory which might have empty spaces is assigned to your `GENY_DIR` variable so I'd think when you quote `CMD` it has no effect. Have you tried to quote your `${GENY_DIR}` and see how it behaved ?

Comment: Thanks guys, storing it in an array as suggested by @that other guy worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to store commands in strings. Use arrays instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
GENY_DIR="$HOME/Documents/My Script/watchdog/genymotion"
BK="$GENY_DIR/background.sh"
DEVICE="164e959b-0e15-443f-b1fd-26d101edb4a5"
CMD=( "$BK" "player" --vm-name "$DEVICE" )
"${CMD[@]}"
```

Arrays properly preserve your word boundaries, so that one argument with spaces remains one argument with spaces.

Due to the way word splitting works, adding a literal backslash in front of or quotes around the space will not have a useful effect.

John1024 suggests a good source for additional reading: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: `./main.sh: line 5: 'home/user/Documents/My Script/watchdog/genymotion/background.sh': No such file or directory` is the error message returned when trying to run as an array. I confirmed that the file exists :)

Comment: I copied your code, I don't know where your files are. Are you sure there wasn't supposed to be a `/` in front of that?

Comment: Yes sorry, there is a `/` in front of home, i use the $HOME variable but i typed it out for this.

Comment: No, it was just a typo in my example, i have the \ in my actual script, that line is `GENY_DIR="$HOME/Documents/My Script/watchdog/genymotion"`

Comment: Ok. It's tricky to debug by proxy when you're running one version and posting another. What is the actual error message? The error you posted said `line 5`, but that would not happen on line 5 as posted in this solution.

Comment: Works, thank you very much! I had an excess `'` single quotes i was trying out. I tried your code again in a new file and it worked like a charm!

Comment: +1.  Also, for good background reading on this, see: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
GENY_DIR="home/user/Documents/My\ Script/watchdog/genymotion"
```

You can escape the space with a backslash.

Comment: `./main.sh: line 5: '/home/user/Documents/My\: No such file or directory`